# Datatable with Angular 8, node and mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, angular, datatable, sequelize.js

Currently i am building application in which i need datatable functionality using angular, node and mysql.

I checked link @https://www.npmjs.com/package/datatables-query,  but this is for mongodb. I need for mysql.

Also let me know if another best option is available.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are many option for datatable with angular, you can use this link or even you can use material ui datatable. `http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/welcome`

Comment: Right, but it is angular side, from node side any library to handle that requests or we need to make it work manually?? I am looking for combo of angular and node both.

Comment: Why not you are using server side pagination?